# Poems or stories with no repeated words?

Tags: terminology, style

I am after a poem/story that has no repetitions in words, further, is this a type of writing style? Are there any famous examples where this is the case?

> [Repetition is the act of repeating or restating](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/repetition-examples-in-writing.html) something more than once. In writing, repetition can occur at many levels: with individual letters and sounds, single words, phrases, or even ideas.

Comment: Requests for lists of works are off topic

Comment: “For sale: baby shoes, never worn.”

Comment: "A butterfly; fluttered by"